# why redux form autosubmit and then get request?

Tags: redux-form

**Intro:**

For learning redux form I followed this youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itlSR3hm5AM) but I do not get the same behavior the Author has there (I didn't use his template, but just realized his component in my working template).

**What I expected:**

- To have the redux form output form values after submitting, to the console

- If I submit the form, NO get request made, but values only print in console

**What I get in reality:**

- Redux form seems to auto submit in initialization step and I get empty form object in console right when navigating to localhost:3000

- If I press submit, Redux form will make a get request, while I still didn't prepared my backend.

My code (followed simply from youtube) is, first the form:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class ReduxFormTrial extends Component{
  render(){
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit()}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name Here:</label>
        <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
   )
  }
 }

 ReduxFormTrial = reduxForm({form: 'contact'})(ReduxFormTrial);
 export default ReduxFormTrial;
```

Then the component including it, for representation:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReduxFormTrial from './reduxformtrial';

export default class ReduxFormHOC extends Component{
  submit = (values) => {
  // print the form values to the console
  console.log(values)
  }
  render(){
   return (
     <ReduxFormTrial onSubmit={this.submit}/>
   )
  }
}
```

**Please let me know:**

- how to stop the redux form from auto submiting (publishing empty values on initialization) 
- how to prevent it from sending get request?(I expect somewhere to have e.preventDefault() but I don't know where to put it?)

**Edit:**

I got rid of this issue by editing my form this way:

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.onSubmit)}>
```

but perhaps I'm doing all in a wrong way, so I'd still wait for the correct way if somebody kindly hopefully will suggest it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you realize what your issue was here? (not talking about the workaround)

Comment: No, could you please make me clear? It'd be very helpful. Time passed and I read it again, still can not figure out why! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it because of initialization stage with empty props supplied like from the constructor? I can't come to other ideas at the moment.

Comment: `<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit()}>` should be `<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>`

Comment: surprised that I couldn't see that such a long time! I've had similar issues and finally learned to remove that "()", but this one always escaped! Thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem haha it's an easy miss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit()}>
```

You should write:

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
```